# Parity of spherical harmonic vector

Tags: quantum-field-theory, parity, spherical-harmonics

I am reading a book about photon. It derived the spherical harmonic vectors of the photons. One of them is

$$\vec{Y}^{(e)}_{jm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{j(j+1)}} \nabla_\vec{n}Y_{jm} $$

and it says its parity is $(-1)^j$.

I thought parity of $Y_{jm}$ is $(-1)^j$ already. So with $\nabla_\vec{n}$, it should become $(-1)^{(j+1)}$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is $\nabla_{\vec{n}}$ a directional derivative?